# html img default+hover+onclick

Tags: html, css, image, onclick, hover

im pretty new at coding and im struggling right now.

I currently have image with text appearing when i hover it. Using overlay + opacity.

What I would like to have:

img = [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzvH4.jpg)

img hover = [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkIky.jpg)

img on click = the text with the orange background wich i currently have on hover.

Thanks for the help and sorry for my english.

EDIT: here is the code.
EDIT2: i would like to make it look like this but with text as onclick, not a picture. Basically the same looking text as i have currently got on hover:

> img src="image1" alt="image"
>
> onmouseover="this.src='image2';"
>
> onclick="this.src='image3';
>
> onmouseout="this.src='image1';"

```css
.item .item-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.item .item-wrap a {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item .item-wrap .overlay {
  background: #ed560e;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  opacity: 0;
  zoom: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.item .item-wrap img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.item .item-wrap .bieres-item-meta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  opacity: 0;
  zoom: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.item .item-wrap .bieres-item-meta h5 {
  font: 15px/21px"raleway-heavy", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.item .item-wrap .bieres-item-meta p {
  font: 14px/18px"raleway-semibold", sans-serif;
  color: #fbcab3;
  margin: 0;
}
/* on item hover */

.item:hover .overlay {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  opacity: 1;
  zoom: 1;
}
.item:hover .bieres-item-meta {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  opacity: 1;
  zoom: 1;
}
.item:hover .item-wrap img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="bgrid item">
  <div class="item-wrap">

    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://v5.lapiece.ch/images/portfolio/mobykid.jpg" alt="Moby Kid">
    </a>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="bieres-item-meta">
      <h5>Moby Kid</h5>
      </br>
      <p style="margin-right: 20px;">
        Apparence: Robe jaune pâle et trouble. Bonne tenue de mousse.</br>
        </br>
        Arôme: Fruité avec des notes de banane.</br>
        </br>
        Goût: Légèrement acidulé, avec des saveurs nets d'agrumes et discrètes de fruits tropicaux.
        </br>
        </br>
        Alcool: 4.5 [ % ]</br>
        Couleur: 6 [ EBC ]</br>
        Amertume: 18 [ IBU ]</br>
        Densité finale: 1009 [ g/l ]</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **"You guys can probably check my index and css directly trough your browser"** - probably we could. but we wont. please isolate the relevant code and paste it in your question.

Comment: Sorry it's my first post in here. Should i embed my whole index.html and css file?

Comment: no, only isolate the relevant code. you are having an issue with an image and hovering over it, this is the only code that needs to be embedded.

Comment: ok i just edited my first post.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this - For hovering effect

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.imgBox
{
    width: 441px;
    height: 248px;
    background: url(img1.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.imgBox:hover
{
     background: url(img2.jpg) no-repeat;
     <!--These are optional-->
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="imgBox">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is the basic code. You must tweak according to your page

Comment: wich is where i struggle... :) Check my main post

Answer (score 0):

Just put an image in the background of your overlay class

```
background-image: url('something.jpg');
```

Comment: yeah but how to transfer the current text i have when i hover to the result of a click? without being redirected to another html page?

Comment: Put your text in a div that has display: none inside your overlay, then make onclick trigger a function instead that does everything you need, like showing that div with the text in it (display: block), and swapping images, etc.

Comment: dont really understand... Could you put the code to use for that by any chance?

Comment: Instead of writing js code right in your onclick= you can do something like onclick=showContent then write a function called showContent that does multiple things like controlling the display properties of your text and images and stuff. I don't have time to write that at the moment but you can look up how to do that pretty easily